# Aparência de Combobox no bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, chosen

Olá!

Estou tentando usar o [Chosen + Bootstrap](http://alxlit.name/bootstrap-chosen/) no Laravel.

Mas gostaria que a aparência usando o choosen ficasse como no bootstrap mesmo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Analise a imagem acima:

Na opção 1 sem usar o Laravel usando Choosen fica do jeito como é no bootstrap;

Na opção 2 usando o Laravel fica bem pequeno.

Em ambas as opções chamo desse jeito:

```js
 $('#cidades').chosen( {
              allow_single_deselect: true,
              search_contains: true,
              no_results_text: "Nenhum resultado enontrado!"
          } );
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.3/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.3/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>





<div class="form-group ">
   <label for="tipoos" class="col-md-1 control-label">Cidades</label>
   <div class="col-md-3">
      <select  class="form-control"  id="cidades" data-placeholder="Selecione a cidade">
         <option value="0"></option>
         <option value="1">Manaus</option>
         <option value="1">Boa Vista</option>
         <option value="2">São Paulo</option>
       </select>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você confundiu o https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen com o https://github.com/alxlit/bootstrap-chosen, este CDN que você usou não é o mesmo do link http://alxlit.name/bootstrap-chosen/, são projetos diferentes com nomes semelhantes apenas.

No repositório do @alxlit se você baixar a versão 1.0.1 na aba releases a aparencia é quase idêntica ao do bootstrap:

- https://github.com/alxlit/bootstrap-chosen/releases

No entanto se deseja usar o `harvesthq/chosen` basta usar o seletor `.chosen-container-single .chosen-single` para o elemento "select" e os seguintes para o arrow:

- `.chosen-container-single .chosen-single div b` (menu fechado)
- `.chosen-container-active.chosen-with-drop .chosen-single div b` (menu aberto)

Que é o seletor usado no *Chosen* e customizar como desejar, até mesmo para ficar parecido com o do Bootstrap.

```js
$('#cidades').chosen( {
              allow_single_deselect: true,
              search_contains: true,
              no_results_text: "Nenhum resultado enontrado!"
          } );
```

```css
.chosen-container-single .chosen-single {
    background-color: #ffffff !important;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box !important;
    -moz-background-clip: padding !important;
    background-clip: padding-box !important;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc !important;
    border-radius: 4px !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075) !important;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075) !important;
    color: #555555 !important;
    display: block !important;
    height: 34px !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    line-height: 34px !important;
    padding: 0 0 0 8px !important;
    position: relative !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    white-space: nowrap !important;
    background-image: none !important;
}

.chosen-container-single .chosen-single div b {
     background-position: 1px 5px !important;
}

.chosen-container-active.chosen-with-drop .chosen-single div b {
     background-position: -15px 5px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.3/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.3/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="form-group ">
   <label for="tipoos" class="col-md-1 control-label">Cidades</label>
   <div class="col-md-3">
      <select  class="form-control"  id="cidades" data-placeholder="Selecione a cidade">
         <option value="0"></option>
         <option value="1">Manaus</option>
         <option value="1">Boa Vista</option>
         <option value="2">São Paulo</option>
       </select>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode aplicar estilos abaixo que irão aumentar o tamanho do tema. Apliquei alguns estilos que irão aumentar o tamanho da fonte e dimensões dos elementos (vide comentários no CSS).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
$('#cidades').chosen({
   allow_single_deselect: true,
   search_contains: true,
   no_results_text: "Nenhum resultado enontrado!"
});
```

```css
/*ajustes do select*/
select.form-control + .chosen-container.chosen-container-single .chosen-single{
    height: 40px; /*altura*/
    padding: 6px 10px; /*ajuste do espaçamento vertical/horizontal*/
    font-size: 18px; /*tamanho da fonte*/
}

/*seta*/
select.form-control + .chosen-container.chosen-container-single .chosen-single div{
    top: 8px;
}

/*ícone de deselecionar*/
select.form-control + .chosen-container.chosen-container-single .search-choice-close{
    top: 14px;
}

/*caixa de texto*/
select.form-control + .chosen-container .chosen-search input[type=text] {
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 18px;
}

/*resultados*/
select.form-control + .chosen-container .chosen-results {
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.3/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.3/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group ">
   <label for="tipoos" class="col-md-1 control-label">Cidades</label>
   <div class="col-md-3">
      <select  class="form-control"  id="cidades" data-placeholder="Selecione a cidade">
         <option value="0"></option>
         <option value="1">Manaus</option>
         <option value="1">Boa Vista</option>
         <option value="2">São Paulo</option>
       </select>
   </div>
</div>
```